# Center data in table php

Tags: html, css

I have a  Html table within a PHP document. The data is being called in php through MySQL server. I am trying to center the data that is called to the table. I have tried in the table structure html it will center the header of the table, but not the data that is being called.

Here is what I have where the data is being called:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>".$datars."</td>
    <td>".$data->Room."</td>
    <td>".$data->Patient."</td>
    <td>".$dataacuity."</td>
    <td>".$data->TSLS."</td>
    <td>".$data->OLOS."</td>
    <td>".$data->CurrentLoc."</td>
    <td>".$data->InPat."</td>
    <td>".$datalo."</td>
    <td>".$datalc."</td>
    <td>".$datamee."</td>
    <td>".$dataekg."</td>
    <td>".$nurse."</td>
    <td>".$stetores."</td>
    <td>".$data->Nurse."</td>
    <td>".$data->Physicain."</td>
</tr>";
```

I have tried adding :

```
 <td align="center" valign="middle">
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: CSS `.td { text-align: center;}`?

Comment: @MikeBrant no `.` on the front of that that would represent that its a `CSS Class`

Comment: the question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: http://html.net/tutorials/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CSS` or an `Inline Style`, the first is far better then the latter.

CSS

```
td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Inline Style

```
<td style="text-align: center">your data</td>
```